# Which OS will be reinstalled with a factory reset from a dual boot?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, restore

I have a computer that had been installed with a dual-boot. Currently, there is when I start a grub kernel that handles two OS on multiple partitions (sda1 to sda4):

- Ubuntu
- Windows (with some remote accounts)

I have access to the Ubuntu account, but not to the Windows account. I think that I can launch a command to reset the computer to factory parameters (not sure that Ubuntu has "more" rights that the Windows account).

My question is what will happen if I reset from the factory parameters from the *Ubuntu* account:

- It will reset the parameters of the computer
- Will it re-install Windows?
- Will it re-install Ubuntu?
- For both installations: with or without the dual-boot?

I tried already to open the Windows account with Rescapp, but it did not work.

**EDIT:**
About factory resetting from Ubuntu: I just learnt it does not really exist as a built-in command. So to make the question more clear:

- What if I use a tool for factory reset such as [Resetter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591167/resetting-ubuntu-to-factory-settings)?
- Is there a better solution for my problem with command line, and which one?

Comment: Which command? It kinda depends on what you are considering to do.

Comment: @Stefan I edited according to your comment; Apparently no command line exist for factory reset. Maybe in the BIOS?

Comment: It is not clear what you are intending to do. You probably don't have a factory image on your device. Android will (probably) do this my having the factory settings in ROM, and then overlaying changes. These changes can be wiped to do the factory reset.  MS-Windows also has some check-pointing. Gnu/Linux **could** have this, but is almost certainly not enabled. Tell us what you want to do, and we can tell you how. You can recover user data (if not encrypted with a lost key). You can re-install the operating systems (MS-Windows often has problems with licence keys, but that is life as MS user)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to Windows, you don't need a factory reset of Ubuntu but a way to [reset your password](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4490115/windows-change-or-reset-your-password) or [restore your Windows Installation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options).

When you reset Ubuntu using [Resetter](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter) you won't have changed anything about your Windows Installation. Unless you reinstall Ubuntu where you format the whole disk it will not do anything to your Windows partition.

Likewise, a Windows factory reset should not delete your Linux partition but it might override your boot loader. Cf. [Will Windows 10's reset delete my Linux partitions?](https://superuser.com/q/1058268/861215)